# Contains superset

Tags: algorithm, set

I'm on a hunt for a structure ("set of sets") that would allow me efficiently check whether it contains superset of my set.

Example:
    A = { 1, 2 }
    B = { 2, 3 } 
    C = { 1, 3 } 
    D = { 1, 2, 3 }

set of sets S1 = { A, B } and another S2 = { D }

```
S1 contains A => true
S1 contains C => false
S2 contains A => true
```

The solution for this should have as low complexity (not only asymptotic) as possible.

Comment: How large are your sets? How many do you have?

Comment: Sets usually contain less than 5-10 strings (or longs) and set of sets should contain at maximum ~100-1000 sets, but in most of the cases 10-100 sets.

Comment: Can sets themselves or sets of sets change(that is, can there be inserts/deletes) or are they all static?

Comment: Sets are immutable, but sets of sets are not and are basically used as duplicate filters.

Comment: @Jiri Since the inner sets are both small and immutable, have you thought about just enumerating all the subsets and storing them in a hash table? Space would be O(n * 2^m) where n is the number of sets and m is the number of elements per set. Insertion/deletion would be O(2^m) and query O(1)

Answer (score -1):

Use a dictionary to convert between possible distinct elements and positions in a bitmap.  Then store each set as a bitmap.

Taking the union of a set of sets is a question of oring together the bit maps.

Checking whether one set is a subset of a set of sets is checking the anding the bit maps results in the smaller set's bitmap.

These operations should be fast.  And if you were *really* ambitious, you could start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units and figure out how to move the computation to a GPU.

If you had larger sets and were OK with sometimes getting the wrong answer, then you should look up Bloom Filters.  This lets you get mostly right answers with significantly shorter bitmaps.